# How automatically to forward bitcoins from one address to another?

Tags: transactions, client, blockchain-wallet-app

I have a bitcoin wallet address (the private key is known by other people). I periodically receive payment on this address (and cannot change it/receive to other address).

I need:
When I receive a payment on it, automatically and immediately (at 0 confirmations, like in BlockChain.info wallet) send/forward them to my new wallet address (the private key is known only by me).

Is this possible and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically send bitcoins from one wallet to another?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-send-bitcoins-from-one-wallet-to-another)

Comment: This is what I wanted. Using one address to receive payments and another one to spend. And a way to link these two addresses..

Comment: May be confusing, but this will be useful many cases. I don't have change my address for every tx, and I don't have to worry about loss of control of this account.

Comment: @JamieBull, does not seem to be duplicate. The OP here explicitly says that the receiving addresses' private is shared with other people, while the linked question does not have such a condition. Due to this, the solutions may differ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use /etc/crontab on your Ubuntu:

```
* * * * * root /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bitcoin_resender
```

And script shall looks like:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/bitcoin_resender
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(echo "$(bitcoind getbalance) > 0" | bc) -eq 1 ];then
      bitcoind sendtoaddress YOUR_NEW_ADDRESS $(bitcoind getbalance) "Comment for resender"
fi
```

It will check every minutes your bitcoind balance and resend each bitcoins to YOUR_NEW_ADDRESS.

Your probably need to check the fee.

Comment: Code answer is best answer.

Comment: And what about fees? `error: {"code":-4,"message":"Error: This transaction requires a transaction fee of at least 0.024 because of its amount, complexity, or use of recently received funds!"}`

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible.
You need to write your own software for this.

As a workaround, maybe you can import this receiving address to spending wallet?